# Razor engine can't find my view in .Net Core class library

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, class-library

I have my class library, which consists of `ViewRenderService` class:

```
public interface IViewRenderService
    {
        Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model);
    }

    public class ViewRenderService : IViewRenderService
    {
        private readonly IRazorViewEngine _razorViewEngine;
        private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public ViewRenderService(IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
            ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
            _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string viewName, object model)
        {
            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = _serviceProvider };
            var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, viewName, false);

                if (viewResult.View == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException($"{viewName} does not match any available view");
                }

                var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = model
                };

                var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                    actionContext,
                    viewResult.View,
                    viewDictionary,
                    new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),
                    sw,
                    new HtmlHelperOptions()
                );

                await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);
                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }
```

and a lot of views, which start from the path: *my class library root/Views//Shared/many views*.

The problem is, that `IRazorViewEngine` can't find my views, how should I call `viewRenderService.RenderToStringAsync(?)` to render `~/Views/Shared/Myview.cshtml`, for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I handle views in class libraries is to make the views embedded resources, ie in the .csproj file I have

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\**" Exclude="bin\**;obj\**;**\*.xproj;packages\**;@(EmbeddedResource)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and you need this package:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="1.1.*" />
```

and then I have an extension method in my class library like this:

```
public static RazorViewEngineOptions AddCloudscribeSimpleContentBootstrap3Views(this RazorViewEngineOptions options)
{
    options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(
        typeof(Bootstrap3).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
        "cloudscribe.SimpleContent.Web.Views.Bootstrap3"
    ));

    return options;
}
```

and then in Startup.cs of the main app you have to opt in to including those views using the extension method like this:

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddRazorOptions(options =>
{
    options.AddCloudscribeSimpleContentBootstrap3Views();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it!

Comment: I've tried, it doesn't work. Still `viewResult` searches in _/Views/Myview.cshtml_ and _/Views/Shared/Myview.cshtml_ and can't find   `Myview.cshtml`, however, I have it in _/Views/Shared/_ where `razorViewEngine` did the search!

Comment: it should work, it does work for me. definitely will require rebuild solution to make sure it re-compiles and includes the embedded files

Comment: I can't understand, what does this line mean: `"cloudscribe.SimpleContent.Web.Views.Bootstrap3"`?

Comment: that is the full assembly name from my class library that has embedded views, you should replace that with the name of your assembly

Comment: Ok, when I'm starting it from Visual Studio in debug, it works, however, I can't publish, a lot of mistakes suddenly appear in _cshtml_s, while publishing.

Comment: are they errors or just warnings? For me there are some warnings that I just ignore, because my models are not in the class library with the views and are not referenced because that would make circular dependencies. I just pack my class library with the views as nuget packages and consume the nuget. you can see my nuget with the views has very few dependencies and it publishes just fine as a nuget even though the models referenced in the views are unknown http://www.nuget.org/packages/cloudscribe.Core.Web.Views.Bootstrap3/1.1.0-rc20170702

Comment: also make sure you are just embedding the views as resources not trying to pre-compile them, that would cause errors about unknown model types unless the views library has references to the models

Comment: Errors, but it works, however, I have references to the models, without any troubles with circular dependencies. What do you mean by no pre-compiling views?

Answer (score 3):

**Update for ASP.NET Core 2.0**

In your library .csproj, you should have the following (everything else mentioning your views can be removed/commented):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="Views\xxx\_MyView.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Note the `Content Update=` that replaces a `Content Includes=`, it gave me some hard time to find what was wrong :)

As well as the `.Razor` of `Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor"` which embeds views correctly.

Comment: @JohnZabroski Possible, but why would you?
Here the lib is still compatible .net standard and therefore probably lighter. You should do it only if you need it, otherwise just include the required dependencies.

Comment: I meant use TargetFrameworks property like so: `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>` - maybe I am missing your point about "do it only if you need it" - if you're writing libraries, you can't anticipate how those libraries will be used, so the IF is non-determinable at project-file-write-time.

Answer (score 2):

**Update for .Net Core 3.1**

After struggling for a while myself with the same problem @Jean's answer was of great help. Here's my .Net Core 3.1 update of that answer. Hope it will help other people.

This is in the .csproj file of the .Net Core 3.1 class library:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>  
    <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="Views\**\*.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

This is the file structure in the library.

[image]

To invoke the View Component in the library from the web app use this:

```
 @await Component.InvokeAsync("GoogleAnalytics")
```

Comment: Not working at my project using .net 5. Any suggestions? Have those things changed again?

Answer (score 0):

I was copying old template files and replacing content, and it was adding them in the csproj like this...
These were not getting picked up with finding the view.

Commenting this out made it work

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="EmailTemplates\ConfirmEmail.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="EmailTemplates\ForgotPassword.cshtml" />
   
  </ItemGroup>
```